# Height 100% en componente Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, component, livewire, height

Esto va a sonar un poco enredado.

Tengo un archivo index.blade.php, este llama a un componente General de Livewire llamado new-template, y este componente llama a otro componente llamado sale.blade.php

En realidad New-Template tiene un menu el cual permite cambiar las vistas (como una SPA) el detalle es el siguiente

**INDEX**

```
 * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.parent-container{
    background: var(--clr);
    background: red;
    display: block;
    height: calc(100vh - 105px);
}

 <div class="parent-container">
        @livewire('new-template')
 </div>
```

**NEW-TEMPLATE**

```
<div>
@switch ($view) 
    @case ('views.home')
        @livewire('views.home')
        @break
    @case ('views.register')
        @livewire('views.register')
        @break
    @case ('views.sales')
        @livewire('views.sales')
        @break
@endswitch
</div>
```

**SALES.BLADE.PHP**

```
<style>
.body{
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}
</style>
<div>
<div class="body">
    
</div>
</div>
```

Si, se que tener el CSS en el componente no esta bien y tal, es solo para ejemplificar.

El detalle es que no logro hacer que el **.body** ocupe el 100% de la pantalla.
Pero, si sacase el body fuera del los componentes, es decir

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.parent-container{
    background: var(--clr);
    background: red;
    display: block;
    height: calc(100vh - 105px);
}
.body{
    display: block;
    background: blue;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
}
 <div class="parent-container">
        <div class="body"></div>
 </div>
```

Entonces aqui sin funciona y el body ocupa el 100% de la pantalla.

Lo tengo asi...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero que este asi... (Esto pasa cuando lo saco del componente)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Encontre la solucion. Olvidé que siempre que creas un nuevo componente Livewire, este va encapsulado en un Div.
La solucion esta en asignarle a este Div una clase.

Asignale una clase y controla su tamaño como quieras.

```
<style> 
.MYCLASE{
 heitgh:100%;
}
</style>

<div class="MYCLASE">
@switch ($view) 
@case ('views.home')
    @livewire('views.home')
    @break
@case ('views.register')
    @livewire('views.register')
    @break
@case ('views.sales')
    @livewire('views.sales')
    @break
@endswitch
</div>
```